# Compute shader: Property at kernel index is not set

Tags: unity, compute-shader

I am trying to follow this excellent Coding Adventure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lctXaT9pxA0 in order to get a very simple mesh deformation on a mesh using a compute shader.

I'm getting an error that reads:

> Compute shader (NewComputeShader): Property (vertices) at kernel index (0) is not set
> UnityEngine.ComputeShader:Dispatch(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)
> MoonShader:runShader() (at Assets/MoonShader.cs:27)
> MoonShader:Update() (at Assets/MoonShader.cs:15)

I'm calling runShader() in Update (maybe that's a terrible idea, but I don't think it's contributing to this specific problem yet).

Do I need to somehow pass my mesh's vertices into `StructuredBuffer<float3> vertices;`? If so, how am I supposed to do that?

This is the call to the compute shader in my .cs file.

```
void runShader() {
    int kernelHandle = computeShader.FindKernel("CSMain");
    computeShader.Dispatch(kernelHandle, 512, 1, 1); //this is the line it appears to be complaining about
}
```

This is my .compute file.

```
#pragma kernel CSMain
StructuredBuffer<float3> vertices;
RWStructuredBuffer<float> heights;
uint numVertices;
float testValue = 20;

[numthreads(512,1,1)]
void CSMain (uint id : SV_DispatchThreadID) {
    if(id >= numVertices) {

    } else {
        float3 vertexPosition = vertices[id];
        heights[id] = 1 + sin(vertexPosition.y * testValue) * 0.05;
    }
}
```

Link to repo if it's helpful: https://github.com/glenpierce/proceduralPlanets

Answer (score 1):

You need "link" your StructuredBuffer to a ComputeBuffer that you initialize in the CS script. In your code, you've never specified a compute shader to write to, so the compiler is basically saying, "yo, there's nowhere to write this data to!"

In your .cs file, you should have:

```
void runShader() {
    
    int kernelHandle = computeShader.FindKernel("CSMain");
    //New Things here
    ComputeBuffer vertexBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(mesh.vertices.Length, sizeof(float) * 3); //make new compute buffer with specified size, and specified "stride"
    //stride is like the size of each element, in your case it would be 3 floats, since Vector3 is 3 floats.
    vertexBuffer.setData(mesh.vertices); //set data inside buffer

    computeShader.setBuffer(kernelHandle, "vertices", vertexBuffer); //Linking the compute shader and cs shader buffers


    computeShader.Dispatch(kernelHandle, 512, 1, 1);
}
```

I hope that helps!

I'd also recommend checking out these two ComputeShader guides, the OP walks you through his own personal project and explains things pretty well.

(Easy) https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/7pa6bq/drawing_mandelbrot_fractal_using_gpu_compute/

(Hard)
https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/7ppldz/physics_simulation_on_gpu_with_compute_shader_in/

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting errors on these two lines now:         
        vertexBuffer.setData(mesh.vertices);
        computeShader.setBuffer(kernelHandle, "vertices", vertexBuffer);                                       both of the errors are complaining: does not contain a definition for ____ and no accessible extension method ____ accepting a first argument of type 'ComputeBuffer' The first argument in one case is a Vertex3[] and next case is an int. This error is super-confusing and I don't see any reference to how it's even possible. Do you have any idea where it might come from?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Assets\MoonShader.cs(26,23): error CS1061: 'ComputeShader' does not contain a definition for 'setBuffer' and no accessible extension method 'setBuffer' accepting a first argument of type 'ComputeShader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Assets\MoonShader.cs(25,22): error CS1061: 'ComputeBuffer' does not contain a definition for 'setData' and no accessible extension method 'setData' accepting a first argument of type 'ComputeBuffer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is particularly odd about these is that neither of the first arguments are ComputeBuffers. vertexBuffer.setData is being called on GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices and computeShader.setBuffer(computeShader.FindKernel("CSMain"), "vertices", vertexBuffer)... computeShader.FindKernel("CSMain") is an int.

Comment: Can I ask what version of Unity you are running on? I find it weird that your Unity is telling you that setBuffer doesn't exist. Mine works fine, and I am running 2019.4.2f1

Comment: I'm running version 2019.4.3f1